# Joining some lines in text

Tags: command-line, text-processing

How can I connect some specific lines together in a text file??

For example,

```
INT(6,4,54,4,1,-1,1,1,0,1,1)=
+INT(5,4,23,4,1,1,1,1,0,1,-1)
*(1)
+INT(5,4,23,4,0,1,1,1,0,1,0)
*(-M^2+a^2);
id INT(4,54,4,1,0,1,1,-1,1,1)=
+INT(4,23,4,1,1,1,1,-1,1,0)
*(1);
```

I would like to put the lines starting with * to the line before, i.e.

```
INT(6,4,54,4,1,-1,1,1,0,1,1)=
+INT(5,4,23,4,1,1,1,1,0,1,-1)*(1)
+INT(5,4,23,4,0,1,1,1,0,1,0)*(-M^2+a^2);
id INT(4,54,4,1,0,1,1,-1,1,1)=
+INT(4,23,4,1,1,1,1,-1,1,0)*(1);
```

like this.

I typed

```
sed -i 'N;s/\n\*/\*/g' file_name
```

but it does not work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use code formatting for example input and output, and commands, please: https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```bsh
sed -E ':a ; $!N ; s/\n\*/\*/ ; ta ; P ; D' file_name
```

Or a portable (non-gnu) variation:

```bsh
sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/\n\*/\*/;ta' -e 'P;D' file_name
```

- Add `-i.bak` to do the changes in place of the file and create a backup file.

Source: [gnu.org - sed - manual - Join lines that start with whitespace](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Joining-lines.html).